# '... events that took place...'

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

Is the following sentence correct?

'This video contains a lot of footage of events that took place in the last 80 years.'

It feels kind of double, because an event is something that happens or takes place.

Comment: Did you write this sentence? You write an event *takes place* - *took place* is the past form of *take place*. Why should it be wrong then?

Comment: Event means 'something that happens or takes place.' So I thought that '... an event that takes place...' wasn't correct